# Jenkins - Renaming artifacts when using copy-artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Does anyone know if its possible to rename artifacts on Jenkins after using copy-artifacts and if so how? What would the syntax look like? Groovy Ant style of course.

I managed to copy off the artifacts from a different pipeline however, I wanted to rename the artifacts for different pipelines after using copy-artifacts. Is it possible to?

Comment: You can rename the file a second before you upload it as artifact. You can also rename it a second after you copy it from another job.